# Create column names in specific order pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried the following code which is working but does not generate the expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
columns_total = [int(i/2) if i%2==0 else "id"+str(int(i/2)) for i in range(10)]+["sym"+str(i) for i in range(5)]
index_total = [i for i in  range(5)]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index_total,columns=columns_total)
```

The output I got is:

```
     0  id0    1  id1    2  id2    3  id3    4  id4 sym0 sym1 sym2 sym3 sym4
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The values of the columns arranged are not exactly how I was thinking. The order is:

```
0  id0    1  id1    2  id2    3  id3    4  id4 sym0 sym1 sym2 sym3 sym4
```

Whereas the expected output is:

```
0  id0 sym0   1  id1 sym1   2  id2 sym2   3  id3 sym3   4  id4 sym4
```

Please let me know how to correct the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flatten new values create in tuples with `f-string`s working in python 3.6+:

```
a = [item for x in range(5) for item in (x, f'id{x}', f'sim{x}')]
print (a)
[0, 'id0', 'sim0', 1, 'id1', 'sim1', 2, 'id2', 'sim2', 3, 'id3', 'sim3', 4, 'id4', 'sim4']
```

Solution under `python 3.6`:

```
a = [item for x in range(5) for item in (x, 'id{}'.format(x), 'sim{}'.format(x))]
print (a)
[0, 'id0', 'sim0', 1, 'id1', 'sim1', 2, 'id2', 'sim2', 3, 'id3', 'sim3', 4, 'id4', 'sim4']
```

Performance for `range(5)`:

```
In [216]: %timeit sorted([str(int(i/2)) if i%2==0 else "id"+str(int(i/2)) for i in range(10)]+["sym"+str(i) for i in range(5)],key=lambda x: x[-1])
13.2 µs ± 328 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [217]: %timeit [item for x in range(5) for item in (x, f'id{x}', f'sim{x}')]
3.92 µs ± 319 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [218]: %timeit [item for x in range(5) for item in (x, 'id{}'.format(x), 'sim{}'.format(x))]
5.15 µs ± 83.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Will it execute faster and how much time does it take? Please let me know.

Comment: @JafferWilson - what is `range(5)` in real data? in `5` ? or `1000` ?

Comment: It is giving error:` a = [item for x in range(5) for item in (x, f'id{x}', f'sim{x}')]`
                                                       ^
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It is 5. I want to have an appended number for the column so that I can use them accordingly

Comment: @JafferWilson - Waht is your python version?

Comment: Python 3.5.0 is the version  am using

Comment: @CeliusStingher You should try commenting on your answer my friend. It is hard to comment while I am speaking with jezreal. I will comment on your answer.

Comment: You second solution worked. The Python3.6 one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add `sorted` when creating the list to order them by their last value, that is 0 will always precede 1 and so on:

```
columns_total = sorted([str(int(i/2)) if i%2==0 else "id"+str(int(i/2)) for i in range(10)]+["sym"+str(i) for i in range(5)],key=lambda x: x[-1])
print(columns_total)
```

Output:

```
['0', 'id0', 'sym0', '1', 'id1', 'sym1', '2', 'id2', 'sym2', '3', 'id3', 'sym3', '4', 'id4', 'sym4']
```

### Edit:

As Jezrael pointed out, this won't work when the number exceeds 10. This is the solution I came up with:

```
import re
columns_total = sorted([str(int(i/2)) if i%2==0 else "id"+str(int(i/2)) for i in range(500)]+["sym"+str(i) for i in range(250)],key=lambda x: int(re.findall('\d+',x)[0])) 
print(columns_total)
```

Comment: I cannot upgrade right now as it may have many dependencies. I do not want to get into that stuff. It is better to move one line then to move the whole code. I hope you will understand.

Comment: BTW I have tried using your code as well and I got this error: `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()`

Comment: Comments are not private room chats. My answer does not require upgrading. I was refering to the use of `fstrings`. Answering a comment from jezrael's answer in this answer will just mix things up.

Comment: Did you copy-paste it? I'm running it fine. There should be no `int` type values in the list comprehension, I think you are missing the first `str` I added

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Can you please tell me whether it will maintain the speed if I have 1000 number instead of 5?

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues with 1000 values in a list.

Comment: Great .. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - unfortunately there is problem with sorting `sorted([str(int(i/2)) if i%2==0 else "id"+str(int(i/2)) for i in range(500)]+["sym"+str(i) for i in range(250)],key=lambda x: x[-1])`

Comment: Ah yes, true, for values over 10 the sorting should be done differently. Will fix it in a min

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I hope the answer is good enough now. However it required me to import a module.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - What module?

Comment: `re`I'm using it to extract the digits from the strings and use them to sort. Do you think of anything better?

Comment: @CeliusStingher - yop, also like anky pointed `natsort` should be used here (but necessary install new module)